# get attribute name based on slug

Tags: django, django-views

I have a page listing articles based on categories.
The category is filtered from the slug in the url.

I want to display a tag in the template with the category name.

With `get_context_data` I am able to retrive the slug and use it as `{{categoryslug}}` But how do I get the name of the category given the slug?

**Model.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Article(models.Model):

    title= models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True) 
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete= models.PROTECT, related_name="pcat", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**View.py**

```
class ListArticleView(ListView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = "listcat"
    template_name = "myapp/categories.html"
    paginate_by = 5

def get_queryset(self):
    return Article.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['cat_slug'])


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context=super(ListArticleView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['categoryslug']=self.kwargs['cat_slug']
    return context
```

**URLS.py**

```
path(('/<cat_slug>'), views.ListArticleView.as_view(), name='some_categories'))
```

Comment: You can't, or at least not without querying the database, since multiple `name`s could map to the *same* `slug`. You thus will need to perform a query, but in this view, you retrieve already the article's, so you can query with `myarticle.category.name`.

Comment: Or you can just query for the `Category`, like `Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['cat_slug'])`.

Comment: Ok last solution is fine!